# Laravel get single column result as string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I would like to know is it possible to get column value as string. Instead of array in array:

Current query: `Number::limit('1000')->get(['number'])->toArray()`

The result at the moment is this:

[image: Array in array]

Preferable result:

[image: String instead of array]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before your `toArray()` call, add `pluck('number')`:

```
$result = Number::limit('1000')->get(['number'])->pluck('number')->toArray();
```

That's it! This will pluck just the `number` attributes from your result collection, and give you a single-level array.

---

The reason this works, is because you are getting a Collection back from `get()`:

> All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are an instance of the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection object, including results retrieved via the get method or accessed via a relationship.

And the `pluck` method:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck

---

**Update**

Another, even more succinct method provided by @wunch in the comments:

```
$result = Number::limit('1000')->lists('number')->toArray();
```

Comment: Looks promising, but didn't worked. Still the same array in array result.

Comment: It works now this way: 
`$result = Number::limit('1000')->get(['number'])->toArray();
        $results = collect($result)->flatten();
        dd($results);`

But not this ( first code ):

`$result = Number::limit('1000')->get(['number'])->flatten()->toArray();
        dd($result);`

Comment: Updated my answer. Instead of converting to an array, back to collection, and then to array again... use pluck. The previous solution (`flatten`) works great with a normal collection, but I agree it was failing on an Eloquent collection of objects. Tested locally, and pluck works on an Eloquent collection.

Comment: Excellent! Laravel Collections are super powerful. Just yesterday I finished reading through [this book](http://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/) which I highly recommend. Really cool how you can manipulate data structures with ease.

Comment: This is such a common need that the Laravel Query Builder actually has a built-in method to do the column plucking for you: `Number::limit('1000')->lists('short_name')->all()`. I should also note that if you have a lot of data and are concerned about performance, you should probably add a `select` statement in there to tell the database to only return that column (and not the whole model's data).

Comment: @wunch awesome, wasn't aware of that one. it also appears you can skip the `all()` (just tested locally). updated my answer!